# Proof on LCM; why remainder not strictly less than the divisor?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I'm looking specifically at a question and answer in the student solutions for the 10th edition of Gallian's Abstract Algebra.

> Q. Prove that every integer that is a common multiple of every member of a finite set of
> integers is a multiple of the least common multiple of those integers.

> A. Let $a$ be the least common multiple of every element of the set and $b$ be any common multiple of every element of the set. Write $b = aq + r$ where $0 ≤ r ≤ a$.

My issue is that last '$\le$' where I expected '$<$'.  Am I missing a subtlety here? Don't we always assume that $r < a$ when we use the division algorithm?  When at the end of the proof we show that $r \ge a$ and derive a contradiction, it doesn't seem so much like a contradiction as a proof that $r=a$, based on this setup.

Comment: Yes, it's likely a typo. See the linked dupe for the common proofs.

Comment: Thanks, I hate it when students jump to the conclusion that there's an error in the solutions, so I didn't want to make that mistake.